# obtener datos de 2 tablas

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla factura con los campos numero, fecha y una tabla detalles con los campos numerofactura tienen su llave foranea y todo el asunto. QUIERO OBTENER TODOS LOS DETALLES DE LAS FACTURAS EN UN RANGO DE FECHAS Y LE ESTOY MANDANDO ESTE QUERY :

```
SELECT factura.Numero FROM factura  INNER JOIN detalles 
ON factura.Numero=detalles.NumeroFactura 
AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-17' AND '2018-08-18'
```

PERO ME DEVUELVE NULL.ALGUIEN SABE COMO SOULUCIONARLO?

Comment: intenta con `AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-18 23:59:59' ` y aproposito la forma como lo hacen @alanfcm es mas rapida

Comment: @JackNavaRow ya modifique el query de alanfcm y le puse AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-18 23:59:59' pero tampoco sirve.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para que te podamos dar una ayuda más precisa, ejecuta un `SHOW CREATE TABLE factura;` y un `SHOW CREATE TABLE detalles;` y agrega ambos resultados a la pregunta. Otra cosa que puedes hacer para depurar es probar la consulta sin el `JOIN`, directamente en el manejador, quién sabe si hay **o no** datos con esos criterios: `SELECT Numero FROM factura WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-17' AND '2018-08-18' `

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo de esta forma:

```
SELECT factura.Numero FROM factura  INNER JOIN detalles 
  ON factura.Numero=detalles.NumeroFactura 
WHERE factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-17' AND '2018-08-18'
```

Comment: Gracias pero no funciono me devuelve nada :  MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas). (La consulta tardó 0,0000 segundos.)

Comment: Es el mismo query que yo escribi

Comment: no sirvio, no devuelve nada. Es el mismo query que yo escribi

Comment: No es el mismo, el tuyo no tiene `WHERE`

Comment: @JackNavaRow el campo fecha es datetime

Comment: @JackNavaRow si consulto las facturas por fechas me las devuelve bien y si consulto las facturas diciendole feactura.fecha=detalles.numerofactura me devuelve todo bien . El problema es cuando intento las 2 cosas como esta en el query

Comment: podrias agregar un poco de registros basico a tu respuesta ,la respuesta que te dio @alanfcm es valida puede que el error sea mas conceptual

Comment: @alanfcm el query con where ya lo probe tambien y no devuelve nada

Answer (score 0):

supongo que tu campo de tipo date guarda los datos de esta forma: `2012-01-23 09:24:41`

Intenta de esta forma..

```
SELECT f.Numero FROM factura  AS f
INNER JOIN detalles AS d
  ON f.Numero= d.NumeroFactura 
WHERE f.Fecha BETWEEN  CAST('2018-08-17' AS DATE)  AND  CAST('2018-08-18' AS DATE)
```

En caso de falla, prueba cambiando.. tu cadena de texto (la fecha), con

```
DATE(column_name)
```

Espero haberte ayudado..